# systemd-analyse blame: what is dev-sda1.device?

Tags: boot, systemd, fstab

When I run `systemd-analyse blame`, this is the output:

```
          11.365s dev-sda1.device
          7.844s systemd-udevd.service
          3.603s NetworkManager.service
          2.808s keyboard-setup.service
          2.466s ModemManager.service
          2.406s accounts-daemon.service
          1.758s grub-common.service
          1.730s thermald.service
          1.469s irqbalance.service
           847ms gpu-manager.service
           813ms console-setup.service
           773ms apport.service
           702ms systemd-modules-load.service
           697ms resolvconf.service
           693ms dev-hugepages.mount
           692ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           690ms apparmor.service
           671ms dev-mqueue.mount
           596ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           594ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           500ms systemd-journald.service
           452ms rsyslog.service
           438ms upower.service
           399ms polkitd.service
           358ms networking.service
           355ms ufw.service
           338ms avahi-daemon.service
           251ms packagekit.service
           249ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0830d07e\x2da7a6\x2d410b\x2da495\x2d625777b6a36e.swap
           245ms systemd-rfkill.service
           195ms systemd-logind.service
           194ms wpa_supplicant.service
           176ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           163ms udisks2.service
           162ms ondemand.service
           142ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           119ms plymouth-read-write.service
           102ms alsa-restore.service
           100ms user@1000.service
            96ms user@118.service
            96ms plymouth-start.service
            87ms pppd-dns.service
            86ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            84ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            76ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            75ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            57ms snapd.autoimport.service
            56ms systemd-sysctl.service
            54ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            49ms plymouth-quit.service
            42ms snapd.socket
            40ms setvtrgb.service
            32ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            17ms rtkit-daemon.service
            16ms systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service
            13ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            12ms ureadahead-stop.service
            11ms systemd-random-seed.service
             8ms sddm.service
             7ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             4ms rc-local.service
lines 35-61/61 (END)
```

What is `dev-sda1.device`? What is its importance? If I disable it what will happen?

When I log in into my Kubuntu the splash screen (Breeze) displays for a long time

[image]

Comment: You may want to check your drive/partition (`sda1`) because it's taking an awful long time to mount.

Comment: sda1 is mounting the root.

Comment: @CelticWarrior how to check it ? it is the root partition

Comment: The drive could be failing but it can also be something in the fstab.

Comment: how to know if the problem in fstab?  and how to fix

Comment: i edited the post with the content of my fstab

Answer (score 0):

As per [man systemd.device](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/systemd.device.5.html):

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".device" encodes
>   information about a device unit as exposed in the sysfs/udev(7) device
>   tree.

Other units can use the device units to be available before they run.

What is likely happening: You have a mount for `/dev/sda1` in your `/etc/fstab`. 
Systemd will [parse fstab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/systemd-fstab-generator.8.html) and generate .mount units for each item. This mount unit will have an `After=dev-sda1.device` in it so that it only tries to mount the filesystem once the partitions block device is availible.

You can see which unit is waiting for the device by running:

```
systemctl show dev-sda1.device --property=Before
```

The reason why the device is taking time is the kernel needs to load all the driver modules necessary to access the disk, and then read the partition table. On newer hardware with an SSD, this will be much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what mounts the disk according to `fstab` for your units to work is `udisks2`, and what `dev-sdaX.device` does is access the Linux modules like: PCI (video cards, capture card, etc.), USB Wi-Fi cards, USB Bluetooth dongles, your processor microcode, CD-ROMs, etc..

If you want information about mounting and reading disks, type in a terminal emulator:

- `journalctl -b | grep udisks2` for `udisks2`, and;
- `journalctl -b | grep dev-sda1` for `dev-sda1.device`